# Xbox gold membership needs to be split into two to keep teenagers from fighting - please help!

Tags: xbox-network

I purchased one xbox gold card for family, now my two teenagers are fighting over it...can I purchase another and move one kids stats to that membership?

Comment: Whenever my brother and I were fighting over something like this, my Mum would just take it off us both until we agreed to share, and even sometimes she wouldn't bother giving it back. Give them 3 strikes to play nice and share, then cancel the gold subscription for a month or so. That'll stop the bickering ;-). Other than that I don't think you can split stats etc

Comment: How exactly are they fighting over it? If you only have one Xbox, two Gold memberships may not actually solve anything, depending.

Comment: You might need to clarify. Are they fighting over who's account to apply the Gold to? If so, another card would solve it, but there wouldn't be anything to transfer.

Comment: Can we save the amateur parenting advice for Parenting.se? We're here to deal with the video game problem, not the social issue.

Comment: @Zorpix- The PS4 will also [charge to play online](http://kotaku.com/ps4-video-says-playstation-plus-is-mandatory-for-online-512482325).

Answer (score 9):

In the short term, there isn't much you can do;

You could buy a second Gold account, but there's no way to transfer stats or, more importantly, to share downloaded content and games across accounts. Also, it gets kind of pricey.

In the long term, MS *is* looking to solve this problem with the XBox One with the introduction of [Home Gold Sharing](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2013/08/microsoft-details-home-gold-sharing-program-for-xbox-one/), but sadly, that doesn't help you now with a 360 and kids who, I'm sure, are not particularly patient about such things.

Either way, there's no way to go back in time and split up historical stats and achievements. What's been done on one account has been done on that account forever, and cannot be moved to a different one.

Comment: the only appropriate solution is to organize a multi-stage head-to-head tournament to determine which child is the sole, true, legendary account owner ;-)

Comment: Sharing content is possible on Xbox360 as the console it is downloaded to is the console it is registered to, i.e; it will work online or offline for any user(live account or not).